# are these both sentences have an identical meaning? or each has its own emphasis? "tomorrow is his birthday" "it's his birthday tomorrow"?

Tags: word-meaning

There are 2 sentences have similar (may be identical) meanings.

sentence_1: "tomorrow is his birthday"

sentence_2: "it's his birthday tomorrow"

are these both sentences have an identical meaning? or each has its own emphasis?

Comment: Both statements mean exactly the same thing. I can't even detect any subtle difference in emphasis or nuance.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same meaning, but there can be a difference in emphasis, depending on your interpretation.

The first sentence could emphasize the day, and the second his birthday.

> 1. "*Tomorrow* is his birthday."
> 2. "It's his *birthday* tomorrow."

Of course, the emphasis could also be placed on the other word in each sentence. But I emphasized the particular noun that comes *first* in each sentence. Typically, the first noun that you encounter in a sentence is the one that, everything being equal, tends to be more significant.

This does not have to be the case. However, if there is any subtle difference, this would be it.